# Windows 10 Only run a script that's unchanged?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-task-scheduler, hashing, protected

I have a VHD that I want to auto mount in Win10. It seems I need to create a script to do this and then create a scheduled task to run it.

I may be being paranoid, but how do I know that my script is the same one I wrote?
If that script got changed for something else without my knowledge is there some for of validation that can be done before running it? Say a SHA1 hash that has to match?

Thanks to anyone taking the time to post.

Comment: `Get-Help about_Execution_Policies`, `Get-Help about_signing`, [Introduction to Code Signing](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=106296)

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for your link, I think it will prove very useful for longer scripts, I book marked it for reading later.

I was able to solve my problem by invoking powershell.exe directly and passing my command to mount the VHDX using the -command stwitch. EG:
Run program/script: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Add arguments (optional): -command "mount-diskimage -ImagePath \"X:\YY\ZZ\mydrive.vhdx\"

No external script file required.